# How to use Emacs shortcut key in Mac OS?

Tags: macos, shortcut, textedit, emacs

I know Mac OS supports to some Emacs short-cut key to move cursor in text editor, e.g. Command + f/b/p/n to move cursor left/right/up/down, Command + v to page-down. In Emacs Meta + v is page-up, however the Option + v in Mac OS does not page up but instead print '✓'.

What should I set in Mac OS to make Meta + v works in Mac OS? My OS is Yosemite.

Answer (score 1):

You have to open the Terminal Settings and then you can enable "Use Option as Meta key"

[image]