# Hidden MacOS shortcuts: Control+v -> scrollDown; Control+y -> types 'd'

Tags: macos, keyboard, shortcut, text-editor, emacs

I just became aware of what I feel are  2 hidden macOS Monterey keyboard shortcuts when messing around in the Mac Notes app.

Control+v scrolls down a nondeterministic number of lines.

Control+y pastes from the system's clipboard

I find control+v for scrolling down very useful to get to the bottom of something.

These shortcuts are not in any official Apple documentation online that I checked notably
https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201236
and
https://support.apple.com/guide/notes/keyboard-shortcuts-and-gestures-apd46c25187e/mac

Does anybody know where these shortcuts are documented so I could find more like these?

Comment: ⌃v is baked into Cocoa editing controls.  It's usually bound to page-down.

Comment: Could you suggest please a reference to a documentation about Cocoa editing controls? The links I find are either Apple official documentation about Cocoa implementation details without any direct information about these "hidden" shortcuts or stripped down version of Apple's official shortcut list.

Comment: These key bindings stem from the [Emacs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emacs) editor which is — or at least used to be — very popular among programmers. This means that something like "mac emacs shortcuts" is a decent phrase to toss at your favorite web search engine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are describing some long time (I believe Mac OS 6 and 7 era) emacs editor keybindings.

- [How to use Emacs shortcut key in Mac OS?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/256871/5472)
- [from Stack Overflow: A list of all Emacs keybindings for Mac OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25276248/475228)

The above two links should be a good place to start. Since cocoa is not a current framework, the documentation is archived but still useful.

- https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/EventOverview/TextDefaultsBindings/TextDefaultsBindings.html

Also, many “welcome to emacs” style tutorials will give you lots of ones things to try. You may find not all emacs shortcuts were adopted by Apple, but many basic cursor and word movement ones work.